# How do I start a Troy Bilt Tiller without a key?

Tags: engine

My friend has a Troy Bilt Econo-Horse tiller sitting in his garage from the previous homeowner. He’s never used it. It looks like it has a spot for a battery, but there is no battery and no key. Can it be easily converted to a pull start?

Comment: Why not just order a replacement lock. (which will come with a matching key), install that and a battery, and see if it starts? You may even be able to order a key based on the machine's model and serial numbers; contact the manufacturer's customer service department.

Comment: .. or just hot-wire it. Just open it up and manually make the connection that the key would have made.

Comment: Well, I would have to purchase a battery for either of those options. I was hoping I could convert it to pull start for less money.

Comment: Really your question is "*How can I covert a Troy-Bilt tiller to use a pull start?*", right?

Comment: Yeesh. Many battery-start gas engines don't easily convert to no battery, and these tiny batteries are not expensive...

Comment: If it's a Honda utility engine which comes with both pull and electric start like what's on my BCS tractor... Disconnect the magneto ground, open the fuel stop-cock, set the choke and pull. Not enough info, the Troy-Bilt Econo-Horse line is broad enough to include a multitude of engines used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because small engine repair is off-topic